# Text to speech when phone is asleep - Android

Tags: android, sleep, text-to-speech

I have an app that uses text to speech to inform the user every 10 mins that 10 mins have passed. It currently works fine but if you sleep the phone (press the power button) it no longer plays the sound.

How can i play these sounds even when the phone is asleep?

Comment: Just thinking out aloud so not putting it in as an answer, but if you use a Service wouldn't that work?

Comment: Maybe, I haven't looked into that. Just wondering if it can be done simply.

Comment: Shouldn't think it would be difficult. Lots of services run whilst the phone is asleep which play sound, the music player for example.

Comment: I am probably going to go down the service root, but would be interesting to see if it can be done without.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, your code is not running if divice goes to sleep. In order to make your code running you need to acquire [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) from [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). But in your case you don't need to have the WakeLock acquired all the time. You need to wake you application every 10 minutes. Otherwise your app will just eat battery doing nothing.

In order to wake your application periodically you need to use a special Android's [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Here is an example:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);    
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1,  myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, interval, pendingIntent);
```

You also may send broadcast which you will process in your Service (if you don't want to use Activity).

*EDIT*: Playback will not start unless you explicitly create a SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK. Note that PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK will not work with playback (don't now why, probably it's a bug).

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "Music");
wakeLock.acquire();
...start playback...
wakeLock.release();
```

*EDIT*: Added project that shows an example of running a playback every 60 seconds (even when screen is off and usb cable is disconnected). It can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/playevery60/

Comment: My code is running when it is asleep as it is doing more that just playing the audio. But this is an interesting concept of waking the phone.

Comment: How do you know that code is running? How exactly you can tell this? Note that when you connect your phone to computer via USB it doesn't really go to sleep mode even if screen is off.

Comment: Because it is also doing calculations based on gps co-ords, that have to be run every second. I have tested this on a phone not connected to a computer and the calculations are correct i.e. it has to be running whilst asleep.

Comment: When phone is not connected and screen is off, what makes you think that calculations are actually being done continuously? Calculations may have been resumed just when screen goes on. Can you post the logs for next operation: add logs for each gps calculation iteration, disconnect from computer, make the screen off, wait 30 seconds ( should be around 30 logs from you gps calculation module). Then connect to pc and dump the logs, and post them somewhere.

Comment: My app tracks distance via gps. It gets the gps co-ords every seconds and works out how far you have travel since the last co-ord. This distance is totalled up. I tested my app by going for a 1Km walk in a circle with the phone asleep. It calculated a distance of 1Km. If it did no calculations whilst asleep the distance would be next to nothing since I started the tracking at the same spot I finished it, but it didn't it calculated it perfectly proving it had to be checking the co-ords and totalling up distance whilst asleep. Please can we now drop this and get back to the question in hand.

Comment: No, I won't drop this argument. Because it is a correct one. Please see my edits to answer. I've added an example of project that does what you need.

Comment: I wasn't referring to your answer just your comments about "How can I be sure my code is running whilst asleep?". Your answer is an interesting point but the requirement of the question was for the app to speak whilst asleep not wake the phone speak and go back to sleep. I took on board your point and feel this maybe useful, its just not what is needed.

Comment: Ok. Just last note on this: you can't run code if you do not "wake" the phone. That's a given fact, this is behavior by design for Android java apps. You can though wake phone to different levels: partial, dim screen, bright screen, full wake. The most efficient way would be "partial", but for some reason it's not enough for audio. But "dim" level is sufficient. Even more, when using GPS you probably implicitly acquired "partial" wake lock. You just need to raise it to "dim" to make your audio work.